# how disable cache in price's block on product view to magento2.3?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I need disable the cache in price's block on view product.

I used `cacheable="false"` on view `catalog_product_view.xml`,
but that doesn't work.

```
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```

Comment: @Trenton_M note that the OP originally posted more code that got lost in the formatting. Not that it is necessarily a reproducible example, but just so you know they did post a little more code than it may have originally looked.

Answer (score -1):

try with this

layout/catalog_product_view.xml

add this code in your module or theme

```
  <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices" cacheable="false"/>
  </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: This disables caching for the entire page, not just the block